# Sublime Text 3: How to enable autocomplete with Tab and Enter / Return

Tags: text-editors, autocomplete, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

When I first select a choice with the Tab key from the list of choices, the autocomplete choice is not committed, when I come back and try again, it works.

Why does it work the second time and fail the first time?

Ideally, I would like the choice to commit an autocomplete choice with either, the **Enter** / **Return** key or the **Tab** key. Is that possible?

```
"auto_complete": true,
"auto_complete_commit_on_tab": true,
"auto_complete_commit_trigger_characters":
[
    ".",
    "Enter",
    "Tab"
],
"auto_complete_delay": 50,
"auto_complete_selector": "source, comment, text.plain",
"auto_complete_size_limit": 4194304,
"auto_complete_with_fields": true,
"auto_find_in_selection": true,
"auto_complete_triggers":
[
    {
        "characters": "<",
        "selector": "text.html"
    }
],
"tab_completion": false,
```

Answer (score 4):

### Remembering Autocomplete Choice

The autocomplete is quite elaborate; when you choice to insert "program" when you have entered "pro", the selection will be different when, for instance, you have autocomplete after typing "pr".

### Use Tab or Enter to Commit Auto Complete Selection

Use the following setting:

`{ "auto_complete_commit_on_tab": false }`

Auto completion will commit selection with either tab or enter.

### Add Auto Complete Commit Keys:

Thanks to this web-page: https://sublimetext.userecho.com/communities/1/topics/4670-allow-setting-which-keys-commit-auto-complete for including instructions on how to add key-bindings so that you can commit auto-completion with more keys.

For example: commit auto complete selection with period:

```
{ "keys": ["."], "command": "commit_completion", "context": [{ "key": "auto_complete_visible" }, { "key": "setting.auto_complete_commit_on_tab", "operand": false }] }
```